# relation between isolated storage and "other" category data in windows phone 8/8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage

I've recently been scrathing my head over this question:

What is the relation between **Isolated storage** and **"Other" category**(*Settings -> Phone Storage -> click on the phone progressbar to get details*) of data in *Windows Phone 8/8.1*?

Can I save data to Isolated Storage of my application and those data be considered as part of "other" data in my Windows Phone?

Subsequently: Can those data be removed when Windows automatically clears the "other" storage (when it is out of free space or some special application is used)?

And if yes: Where to store some application-critical files if they should not be removed?

Comment: What do you mean by other?

Comment: Settings -> Phone Storage -> click on the phone progressbar to get details